# How can I use XSLT to combine two XML docs, similar to a SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

I have a database application for students in classes at schools.  I send down a lot of data in a single package to the user interface.  To assemble complex XML, I often have to make multiple data fetches as XML, and then combine them.

I'm trying to find a way to use XSLT to perform something akin to a SQL JOIN.  For example, given the following two XML documents:

```
<Xml>
    <Classes>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11"/>
        <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13"/>
        <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17"/>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19"/>
    </Classes>
</Xml>


<Xml>
    <Students>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="19"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="19"/>
    </Students>
</Xml>
```

I'd like to run them through a single XSLT, to produce the this:

```
<Xml>
    <Classes>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11">
            <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
            <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
        </Class>
        <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13">
            <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
            <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
        </Class>
        <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17">
            <Student Name="Rick Robertson" "/>
            <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
            <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
        </Class>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19">
            <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
            <Student Name="Rick Robertson" />
        </Class>
    </Classes>
</Xml>
```

Notice that I omitted the ClassId attribute from the <Student> nodes.

I can assemble the two XML documents into a single document to pass into the XSLT, if that makes it easier to process.

Since this data comes from a database, I will be JOIN-ing different XML documents.  I might JOIN Classes to Schools, or Grades to Students, or Activities to Schools.  But they will all follow the same pattern: a numeric attribute from the child nodes will correspond to a numeric attribute in the parent node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accomplishing this in XSLT is not quite as straightforward as it would be in SQL, but assuming you assembled the two input files into a single document ahead of time (which I would recommend if it's not problematic for you):

```
<Xml>
    <Classes>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11"/>
        <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13"/>
        <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17"/>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19"/>
    </Classes>
    <Students>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="19"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="19"/>
    </Students>
</Xml>
```

This XSLT can be used to join the data together:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <!-- Key to allow retrieving students by their class -->
  <xsl:key name="kStudentByClass" match="Student" use="@ClassId"/>

  <!-- Identity Template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Copy all attributes for this Class element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <!-- Copy in all students for the current class -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kStudentByClass', @ClassId)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Omit the Students element and Students' ClassId 
       attribute from the output -->
  <xsl:template match="Students | Student/@ClassId" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the input XML above, it produces:

```
<Xml>
  <Classes>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson" />
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson" />
    </Class>
    <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13">
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson" />
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson" />
    </Class>
    <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson" />
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson" />
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson" />
    </Class>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson" />
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson" />
    </Class>
  </Classes>
</Xml>
```

And if you can change your XML a little to indicate the outer and inner group, and which attribute to match on, like this:

```
<Xml>
  <Classes outer="true" matchAttribute="ClassId">
     ....
  </Classes>
  <Students inner="true">
     ....
  </Students>
</Xml>
```

Then you could use this more generic XSLT which, while less efficient, should work for any input similar to the above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="innerItems"
                select="/*/*[@inner = 'true']/*" />
  <xsl:variable name="matchAttribute" 
                select="/*/*[@outer = 'true']/@matchAttribute" />

  <!-- Identity Template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*[@outer = 'true']/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Copy all attributes for this element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <xsl:variable name="matchValue" 
                    select="@*[local-name() = $matchAttribute]"/>
      <!-- Copy in all matching items -->
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="$innerItems[@*[local-name() = $matchAttribute] =
                      $matchValue]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*[@inner = 'true']/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
         select="@*[local-name() != $matchAttribute] | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Omit the inner group element, and the meta attributes-->
  <xsl:template match="/*/*[@inner = 'true'] | @outer | @matchAttribute" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

JLRishe's answer is the correct one and works perfectly, but just in case someone else comes a-looking, if you need to use XSLT to combine the two files, you could do something like this

#### a.xml

```
<Xml>
    <Classes>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11"/>
        <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13"/>
        <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17"/>
        <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19"/>
    </Classes>
</Xml>
```

#### b.xml

```
<Xml>
    <Students>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Bob Johnson" ClassId="19"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="11"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Joe Jackson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="13"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="17"/>
        <Student Name="Rick Robertson" ClassId="19"/>
    </Students>
</Xml>
```

#### Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- Apply <Student> elements from b.xml -->
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="document('b.xml')/Xml/Students/Student
          [@ClassId = current()/@ClassId]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Xml>
  <Classes>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="11">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="PHYSICS101" ClassId="13">
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="CALCULUS101" ClassId="17">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Joe Jackson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
    <Class Name="BIOLOGY101" ClassId="19">
      <Student Name="Bob Johnson"/>
      <Student Name="Rick Robertson"/>
    </Class>
  </Classes>
</Xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

JLRishe's answer was great.  I was lost until I got that. (I posted the question.)

Since I know I'm dealing with data from SQL Server, I will always have parent and child nodes that correspond to two tables, and the attributes that connect them are fields from the two tables: an independent table with a primary-key field and a dependent table with a foreign key field.  So I generalized the solution for my very specific needs as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <!-- Parameters to make solution general -->
    <xsl:param name="ParentNode">Class</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ParentIdAttribute">ClassId</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ChildNode">Student</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ChildReferenceAttribute">ClassId</xsl:param>

    <!-- Key to allow retrieving child nodes by the Parent node -->
    <xsl:key name="kChildByParent" match="*[name() = $ChildNode]" use="@*[name()=$ChildReferenceAttribute]"/>

    <!-- Identity Template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Parent Node Matching Template -->
    <xsl:template match="*[name() = $ParentNode]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Copy all attributes and child nodes for the Parent element -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />

            <!-- Copy in all children that reference the current parent -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildByParent', @*[name()=$ParentIdAttribute])" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Omit the child nodes and reference attribute of the child nodes, -->
    <xsl:template match="ChildNodes | *[name() = $ChildNode]/@*[name()=$ChildReferenceAttribute]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Glad you got it solved and understood the solution well enough to modify it yourself! Btw XQuery makes joins very easy, and comes with saxon